# Single word for "a chieftain of thieves"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am in need of a single word for "a chieftain of thieves", if there is any. If there is none, can I use "thieves'-chieftain" instead?

Comment: From Google Books: [the chieftain of thieves](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+chieftain+of+thieves%22), 5 results; [the thieves chieftain](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+thieves+chieftain%22), 9 results; [the arch thief](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+arch+thief%22), **1460** results.

Comment: "Arch thief" gets so many results comparatively because it's mentioned in once in one very famous work, not necessarily because it's used more frequently (in different works) than the others. They're all sort of awkward to me, but I guess that's just personal preference. Can I suggest "king of thieves"?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but perhaps interesting to know: Definition of “**fagin** noun, fagin often capitalized:  an adult who **instructs** others (as children) in crime, [derived from] Fagin, [a] character in Charles Dickens' Oliver Twist (1839).”  Although Fagin, the character, was the leader of his young band of thieves, the common noun *fagin* apparently is just used for one who teaches crime to others (and isn’t necessarily their leader/chief, as you’re seeking).

Answer (score 6):

might I suggest **ringleader**?

**ring·lead·er**

ˈriNGˌlēdər/

noun
a person who initiates or leads an illicit or illegal activity.

Answer (score 2):

**Capo** [sense #2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/capo)

The head of a crime syndicate, especially the Mafia, or a branch of one.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the best alternative would be "**king thief**".

Sorry! I had accidentally written "king thieve" in place of "king thief". I am sorry for the mistake. I did not mean plural, else I would have written "thieves".

Comment: *Thieves* plural, *thief* singular.

Comment: You  are correct. I am sorry. I had accidentally written "king thieve" in place of "king thief". I did not mean plural either, else I would have written "thieves".

Comment: To "ping" a user you must place  @ before their username. When someone leaves a comment, the author of the answer or question  is always notified, that's why I don't have to write out your name.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not always. If you want to be guaranteed that they'll get pinged, yes, but I think sometimes replying next is all it takes.

Comment: In a conversation that might work... (let's see if QPT gets this message )

Comment: Yes. For example I was pinged by DKG's reply. More questions about how comments work? Check the FAQ or come to [chat].

Answer (score 1):

One possible alternative is **kingpin**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_boss) gives some other suggestions.

> A crime boss, crime lord, mob boss, **kingpin**, or Don is a person in charge of a criminal organization.

Comment: "Kingpin" is generic. It does not necessarily refer to a king of thieves.

Answer (score 0):

**Guildmaster** would be a good term for fantasy or science fiction or medieval historical fiction. This comes from the archetypal "thieves' guild" that's prevalent in Dungeons and Dragons and all of it's roll-playing variations over the last 40 years. Many best-selling fantasy authors (R.A. Salvatore, for instance) have used the expression in their works.

Comment: "Guildmaster" is generic. It does not necessarily refer to a king of thieves.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **head thief**

Example: “You see,” the *head thief* began, “we are professional pickpockets. As soon as the guards would enter the barracks, we would slip the cards into their pockets.